# Add a job to linux cron list programmatically with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a job with Nodejs that I want to do it each 30 minutes to scan the Database and Update Products Data in An Ecommerce API with my Nodejs Program, note that the Nodejs Program is serving an REST API (Backend) for a react js web application 
So I searched for that and I found that I can do that with Nodejs Cron Library like "node-schedule" but I know that will be more interesting to do it with Linux Cron

```
 var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
   console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
  });
```

Is there any library that can let me add Cron jobs to Linux using Nodejs Or would I do it with "fs" only? so I will open the cron job file and add my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `crontab` which is part of Vixie Cron allows you to create, edit and delete per-user cron entries.

Or if you are running as the `root` user, which you should *not be doing*, you can drop cron files into `/etc/cron.d`

This is not always supported, and if you're running in a Docker type container environment it is doubtful that you have any cron at all. In that environment you'd want your running Nodejs to handle scheduled jobs for you. Or use some other kind of distributed scheduled work system.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your cron job to a nodejs script. Then adding to the crontab can be done with [cronbee](https://github.com/atmajs/cronbee) module, via API:

```
import { cronbee } from 'cronbee'
await cronbee.ensure({
    taskName: 'do smth',
    taskRun: `node my-script`,
    cron: '42 * * * *'
})
```

or you can ensure the cron job via CLI, if the module is installed globally or from npm scripts:

```sh
$ cronbee ensure mytasks.json
```